# OrderBy boolean of char array

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, sql-order-by

I analyzed code of malware written in C# and came across something unclear to me. The LINQ `OrderBy` method was applied on a `char` array. However, I was suprised about the lambda expression inside, which was similar to the one below.

```
var charArray = "abcdefghijk".ToCharArray();

string generatedString = new string(charArray
  .OrderBy(s => (random.Next(2) % 2) == 0)
  .ToArray());
```

I wonder how it works if the expression value is `bool`. It is also puzzling to me that if I put simple `true` or `false` values there instead, I always get the same `string` of "abcdefghijk" characters. Why is it always mixed up with this expression?

Comment: Code is just showing how to convert an Character Array to a string.  Much simpler to use string generatedString = string.Join("", charArray);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booleans can be ordered - `false` comes before `true`. If you replace the lambda with an `s => true` or `s => false`, you give each character the same boolean value to be sorted by, so the original string order will be retained. With this lambda, you assign a random `true` or `false` value to each character, and the characters are shuffled.

Comment: Oh god, it's so clear now that I'm ashamed to ask. Thank you very much